# Is it possible to get child nodes with the node name as text?

Tags: xpath

I have this weird one-off that I need to do with xpath and I don't even know if it's possible.  So far, I haven't found a way.

```
<things>
<stuff>here are some things <yep>blue</yep> and here are some more things</stuff>
</things>
```

Basically, I want to be able to get the text of "stuff" and all its children as if they are text as well.  For example I want to get this:

`here are some things <yep>blue</yep> and here are some more things`

Comment: Do you want `here are some things blue and here are some more things` or `here are some things <yep>blue</yep> and here are some more things` with the child tag?

Comment: The second one is what I'm looking for.

Comment: hmm .. OK, Not sure if it's possible with pure xpath but let me give a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with the following XPath-2.0 expression:

```
for $p in /things/stuff/node() return if ($p instance of element()) then concat('&lt;',$p/name(),'&gt;',$p,'&lt;/',$p/name(),'&gt;') else $p
```

But this is not a recursive solution, so it works only for the first level of elements.

Comment: It's only one level deep so that should be ok.  Any gotchas with doing this?

Comment: None that I know of except for the mentioned one.

Comment: It's working in xml spy, so I will give it a shot, Thanks!